# retain only rows and columns that match with a string vector

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a large DF with certain columns that have a vector of character values as below. The number of columns varies from dataset to dataset as well as the number of character vectors it holds also varies.

```
 ID                       Country1        Country2    Country3
1  1   Argentina, Japan,USA,Poland,   Argentina,USA    Pakistan
2  2 Colombia, Mexico,Uruguay,Dutch  Mexico,Uruguay Afganisthan
3  3        Argentina, Japan,USA,NA           Japan Khazagistan
4  4 Colombia, Mexico,Uruguay,Dutch Colombia, Dutch North Korea
5  5                   India, China           China        Iran
```

Would like to match them one-to-one with another string vector as below

```
vals_to_find <-c("Argentina","USA","Mexico")
```

If, a column/row matches to anyone of the strings passed would like to retain that column and row. Remove duplicates, and finally remove those values that do not match.

the desired output is as follows

```
  ID Countries.found
1  1  Argentina, USA
2  2          Mexico
3  3  Argentina, USA
4  4          Mexico
```

---

data

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = 1:5, Country1 = c("Argentina, Japan,USA,Poland,", 
"Colombia, Mexico,Uruguay,Dutch", "Argentina, Japan,USA,NA", 
"Colombia, Mexico,Uruguay,Dutch", "India, China"), Country2 = c("Argentina,USA", 
"Mexico,Uruguay", "Japan", "Colombia, Dutch", "China"), Country3 = c("Pakistan", 
"Afganisthan", "Khazagistan", "North Korea", "Iran")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

---

```
dput(df_out) 

structure(list(ID = 1:4, Countries.found = c("Argentina, USA", 
"Mexico", "Argentina, USA", "Mexico")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Instead of a each column as a vector, if the file is read as one value per column. Then, was able do it as below

```
dput(df_out)
structure(list(ID = 1:5, X1 = c("Argentina", "Colombia", "Argentina", 
"Colombia", "India"), X2 = c("Japan", "Mexico", "Japan", "Mexico", 
"China"), X3 = c("USA", "Uruguay", "USA", "Uruguay", NA), X4 = c("Poland", 
"Dutch", NA, "Dutch", NA), X5 = c("Argentina", "Mexico", "Japan", 
"Colombia", "China"), X6 = c("USA", "Uruguay", NA, "Dutch", NA
), X7 = c("Pakistan", "Afganisthan", "Khazagistan", "North Korea", 
"Iran")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))


df_out %>%
  dplyr::select(
    where(~ !all(is.na(.x)))
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(c(1, where(~ any(.x %in% vals_to_find)))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(
    tidyselect::starts_with("X"),
    ~ vals_to_find[match(., vals_to_find)]
  )) %>%
  tidyr::unite("countries_found", tidyselect::starts_with("X"),
               sep = " | ", remove = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE
  )
```

Output

```
 ID                   countries_found
1  1 Argentina | USA | Argentina | USA
2  2                   Mexico | Mexico
3  3                   Argentina | USA
4  4                            Mexico
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unite` the `"Country"` columns, then create a long vector by `separat`ing the values into rows, get all `distinct` values per `ID`, `filter` only those who are in `vals_to_find`, and `summarise` each `countries.found` `toString`.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  unite("Country", starts_with("Country"), sep = ",") %>% 
  separate_rows(Country) %>% 
  distinct(ID, Country) %>% 
  filter(Country %in% vals_to_find) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Countries.found = toString(Country))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     ID Countries.found
  <int> <chr>          
1     1 Argentina, USA 
2     2 Mexico         
3     3 Argentina, USA 
4     4 Mexico
```

Comment: Except that I used a `pivot_longer` for the first step it's 100% the same as my approach. :D

Comment: @Mael how to change `toString` delimiter to something else instead of a comma. I ave other columns to select, is there a better way to select columns when using `summarise`?

Comment: You can use `paste(Country, collapse = " ")`

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with("Country"),
   ~ str_extract_all(.x, str_c(vals_to_find, collapse = "|")))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = NULL, 
     values_to = 'Countries.found') %>%
  unnest(Countries.found) %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Countries.found = toString(Countries.found))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     ID Countries.found
  <int> <chr>          
1     1 Argentina, USA 
2     2 Mexico         
3     3 Argentina, USA 
4     4 Mexico
```